# py-cord | UnboundLocalError: local variable 'embed' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, pycord

```
@bot.slash_command(name = "redeem", description = "Redeem your Key")
async def redeem(ctx, key):
    with open('order_data.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            product, order_key = line.strip().split(':')
            if order_key == key:
                with open('consumed_keys.txt', 'r') as consumed_file:
                    consumed_keys = consumed_file.readlines()
                    if key in consumed_keys:
                        await ctx.send(f"Duplicate key sent by {ctx.author.mention}: {key}")
                    else:
                        with open('consumed_keys.txt', 'a') as consumed_file:
                            consumed_file.write(f'{key}\n')
                        print(f'Successfully verified {ctx.author.name}\'s key: {key}')
                        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Customer')
                        await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
                        ##  EMBED++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                        embed = discord.Embed(
                 title="Order Verification",
        description=f"{ctx.author.mention}, Key Verified",
        color=discord.Colour.green(),
                        )
            embed.add_field(name="Product Name", value=product, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Product Key", value=key, inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text="Test Footer")
            await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
            break
        else:
            print(f'Verification failed by {ctx.author.name}')
            await ctx.send(f"Invalid order id, {ctx.author.mention}")
```

**The Full Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 124, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 982, in _invoke
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\dc bot\redeem bot  rewrite\bot.py", line 38, in redeem
    embed.add_field(name="Product Name", value=product, inline=True)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'embed' referenced before assignment
```

Tried using the command with normal response (no embed) and that worked
i think it says that the function is not closed of the embed but idk how to solve it

Comment: Look closely at your code. Where is `embed` defined? How may that code not get executed so that you would receive an error that it's been defined _before_ assignment.

Comment: @Cfreak i did not understand much what you wrote cuz english aint my main language but embed is defined here `embed = discord.Embed(`

Comment: Also the error shows up when i use an invalid key so the code from `else` schould be getting used

Comment: The embed is only defined inside an `if`, so it won't exist unless the `if` is true

Comment: probably you have wrong indentations - you have `embed = ...` inside `else:` and this makes problem because sometimes it doesn't create `embed = ...`. Maybe you should run `embed = ...` outside `else:` - so you should start `embed = ...` in the same column as `embed.add_field(...)`. OR maybe you should run `embed.add_field(...)` (and rest) inside `else:`

Answer (score 0):

Move the `embed = ...` line to the same indentation of `embed.add_field()` or move all the `embed.add_field()` to the same indentation of `embed = ...`